# Excel - Entering Too many Argument on an IF AND Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Excel is throwing an error with my formula:
**`You have entered too many arguments for this function.`**

> IF(AND(J2="Ounces",K2<=5),VLOOKUP(D2,'Parcel Select oz Lightweight'!$A$2:$B$17,2,0),IF(AND(J2="Ounces",K2>5),VLOOKUP(D2,'First Class oz'!$A$2:$B$17,2,0)),IF(AND(J2="Pounds",K2<=5),INDEX('lb and zones select'!$A$2:$K$73,MATCH(D2,'lb and zones select'!$A$2:$A$73,0),MATCH(H2,('lb and zones select'!$A$2:$K$2))),IF(AND(J2="Pounds",K2>5),INDEX('lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$K$73,MATCH(D2,'lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$A$73,0),MATCH(H2,'lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$K$2,0)))))

I know its a really ugly formula.

Comment: Just break it down to the smallest part and start adding more back it.  Get each individual part working on it's own before putting it together.  it's time consuming but not hard, and you shouldn't expect other to do it because you don't want to. (Besides it's a pretty basic lesson in troubleshooting, which is a pretty basic part programming.)

Comment: Now that I look closer, it has a few problems, and without knowing what you're actually *trying* to do, it's impossible for anyone else to troubleshoot.  Get rid of it and start over, getting each individual if/then result working before putting them together.  Also, just to point out, you're using more functions that `IF` and `AND` as your title states.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, It looks like you just need to use parenthesis properly for each part to all if.

Normal If Block looks like this:

```
IF ( CONDITION,
    <TRUE STATEMENT>,
    <FALSE STATEMENT>
)
```

For nested statements or if, utilize parenthesis. 
Put all nested true and false statement part in parenthesis:

```
IF ( CONDITION,
    (<TRUE STATEMENT>),
    (<FALSE STATEMENT>)
)
```

In this way your code can be look like this:

```
IF ( AND(J2="Ounces",K2<=5),
    (VLOOKUP(D2,'Parcel Select oz Lightweight'!$A$2:$B$17,2,0)),
    (IF(AND(J2="Ounces",K2>5),
            (VLOOKUP(D2,'First Class oz'!$A$2:$B$17,2,0)),
            (IF(AND(J2="Pounds",K2<=5),
                (INDEX('lb and zones select'!$A$2:$K$73,MATCH(D2,'lb and zones select'!$A$2:$A$73,0),MATCH(H2,('lb and zones select'!$A$2:$K$2)))),
                (IF(AND(J2="Pounds",K2>5),
                    (INDEX('lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$K$73,MATCH(D2,'lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$A$73,0),MATCH(H2,'lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$K$2,0))),
                    (<Put a false part here, it was missing your code>)
                ))
            ))
    ))  

)
```

Please check diff for above code and your code to get in detail about where you have missed the opening or closing of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If you break your code out with indentation, you'll see that your first `IF` has 4 arguments (`Condition`, `True Statement`, `False Statement`, `Too Many Statements`) and your second & fourth `IF`s only have 2 arguments:

```c
=IF(
    AND(J2="Ounces",K2<=5), //Condition
    VLOOKUP(D2,'Parcel Select oz Lightweight'!$A$2:$B$17,2,0), //True
    IF( //False
        AND(J2="Ounces",K2>5), //Condition
        VLOOKUP(D2,'First Class oz'!$A$2:$B$17,2,0) //True
    ), //No false?
    IF( //Too many!
        AND(J2="Pounds",K2<=5), //Condition
        INDEX('lb and zones select'!$A$2:$K$73, //True
            MATCH(D2,'lb and zones select'!$A$2:$A$73,0),
            MATCH(H2,('lb and zones select'!$A$2:$K$2)) //Why the brackets?
        ),
        IF( //False
            AND(J2="Pounds",K2>5), //Condition
            INDEX('lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$K$73, //True
                MATCH(D2,'lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$A$73,0),
                MATCH(H2,'lbs and zones priority'!$A$2:$K$2,0)
            ) //No false?
        )
    )
)
```

Looks like you have misplaced a bracket, and need to move it to the end.

(Skipping the `False Statement` statement will just mean that the formula returns `FALSE` in that situation)